# Installation of Openstack via autopilot with only one Disk per Node

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I plan to use autopilot to install a Openstack cloud on a bunch of servers, which have single SSDs installed. The requirements say, 2 disks per node are required, as stated here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-openstack-with-autopilot. 
The machines are currently in production use and we have a limited time frame to get everything up and running, so i have no chance to just give it a try, so after this lengthy preamble my question is:

Is it possible to install Openstack with autopilot on nodes, that have just one physical disk?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the reason for this is that we put the OS on one disk, and use the additional disks for your preferred forms of scale-out storage.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, no it's not.  The requirements are correct.  2 disks are required.